# XDocument.Save(string) not available

Tags: xml, linq, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, linq-to-xml

I'm using VS 2012 Express for Windows 8.I want to load an XML file, modify its content and then save it back to disk.

Up to now, I've been using LINQ to XML and I've been able to load the file, change some node information.

I want to save the file back to the disk using the XDocument.Save(string) method but the intellisense does not include that method though it is documented in the online documentation.

Any idea why?

Thanks

---UPDATE---

Here's what I'm trying to do

```
string questionsXMLPath;
XDocument xmlDocQuestions = null;
StorageFile file = null;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    questionsXMLPath = Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "Assets/Template.xml");
    xmlDocQuestions = XDocument.Load(questionsXMLPath);
}

private async void SomeCodeHereToPopulateControls()
{
    // This Code populates the controls on the Window to edit the XML nodes.
}


private async void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    XElement eleQuestion =
        (from el in xmlDocQuestions.Descendants("Question")
        where (string)el.Element("ID") == txtID.Text
        select el).FirstOrDefault();

    eleQuestion.Elements("Description").FirstOrDefault().ReplaceWith(txtDescription.Text);

    xmlDocQuestions.Save(questionsXMLPath);  // ERROR HERE AND CAN'T COMPILE
}
```

Comment: You need to use the Windows 8 file APIs.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227346.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use the [Windows.Storage APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.aspx). In the sandboxed and asynchronous world of Windows 8, you'll find two significant differences in dealing with file storage:

1. The application can programmatically access data only from the "local storage" for that application UNLESS the end-user has granted specific permission to the app to store/read from elsewhere in the file system (via the [file and folder pickers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR207928))
2. Reading and writing to files is an asynchronous operation, so you'll find most of the file access methods ending in "Async" and you'll use (typically) the [async/await pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) to leverage them

Take a look at the [File access and permissions in Windows Store apps topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx) on the Windows Dev Center for more details as well as the [File access sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-access-sample-d723e597).

In your specific case, you'll just end up writing [XDocument.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341005.aspx) to the desired output file using the techniques shown in the article and the code sample cited above.

By the way, for a more holistic and measured approach to learning about the file system (as well as other concepts unique to Windows Store programming), the [(free) Microsoft App Builder program](http://aka.ms/8in30SO) is a great way to spin up.

Comment: Ok I get it. I shouldn't be able to access the file if this method is not permitted right? By the way, it works with VS 2012 for Windows Desktop so as you said this a completely whole beast. And thanks for the resources.

Comment: well the method doesn't exist (versus not being permitted), so you can't compile.  For other Storage API read methods that you can use, you may still get uauthorized access exceptions at runtime if you try to read a file that the user has not granted explicit permission to.

Comment: You mean permissions in the capabilities section of the manifest file? Is Package.Current.InstalledLocation a common place to work with? Originally, I used this property to access a template.xml file I have compiled with the application. The file is located in the Asset sub-folder. And Document Library capability is enabled, though I'm not sure if this is related...

Comment: Apps always have access to their InstalledLocation so that's fine and common.  Beyond that though, you have to prompt the user in your application (via the pickers) if you want to save it somewhere other than the app's installation location (which isn't too discoverable).  You can't just save to c:/foo/bar.txt w/o having them approving access to that directory. Documents library capability does allow you to save in user's Documents folder w/o asking permission; however, for that to be enabled when you submit to the Store you'll need a business developer (not an individual developer) account.

Comment: Ok. I followed this article ([link](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/how-to-filter-and-sort-xml-data-in-windows-8---winrt)) and everything works as expected except for the file-saving part. Do you have a clue on any alternative based on your last comment?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jim O'Neil's advices, I read MSDN documentation to finally understand that the Asset sub-folder of my application's folder is Read-Only. I used the user's AppData directory and here's the equivalent solution I ended-up implementing, using Streams instead of Strings to Load and Save de XML Document using LINQ to XML:

```
private async void cmdSaveQuestion_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Stream questions = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(@"Template.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists))
        {
            questions.Position = 0;
            xmlDocTemplate = XDocument.Load(questions);

            XElement eleQuestion =
                (from el in xmlDocTemplate.Descendants("Question")
                 where (string)el.Element("ID") == txtID.Text
                 select el).FirstOrDefault();

            eleQuestion.Elements("Description").First().Value = txtDescription.Text;
            eleQuestion.Elements("Active").First().Value = chkActive.IsChecked.ToString();
            questions.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            xmlDocTemplate.Save(questions);
            questions.SetLength(questions.Position);
        }

        LoadTemplateFromXmlFile();
    }
```

I also had to manage the cursor position inside the Stream. Not doing so would write data twice or write in the middle of the file depending on where the cursor is.

Jim, or anyone, You're welcomed to comment if the code can be optimized further.